# Detect mobile application users by google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-website

we have a mobile website. for example link is m.xyz.com. and a android hybrid app in which we are loading m.xyz.com in webview.

We have implemented google analytics tacking in this website to track page view.
In Google analytics, it is showing all users (mobile browser + android app).

we need a real time user in GA of android application and mobile website.

Is it possible? if yes let me know possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot create a custom "real-time" report, but with a little tagging, you can utilize the "Traffic Sources" real-time report.

In your android app, instead of referencing "m.xyz.com" in webview, reference "m.xyz.com?utm_source=myapp&medium=webview", then in the real-time report you should see traffic from Medium "webview" and source "myapp".

Answer (score 0):

we have tried to accomplish this task, but due to time constrain we have not completed our research on this.

Finally We have choose option to publish same website on new subdomail (m2.xyz.com) with new tracking code.